# PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu with php5-mcrypt: Unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, php-5.5

I have an ubuntu server running with PHP 5.5

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2 (cli) (built: Oct  9 2013 14:49:12) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

I´m trying to install `php5-mcrypt` now, but i get following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mcrypt : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I understand, that somehow the mcrypt package is not compatible with my current PHP version, but how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your repos are up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You may have held packages. You can get a list of actual held packages with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

And then you can remove any that don't look right:

```
apt-get remove "package_name"
```

BTW - that looks like a php 5.3 package.